# Radio Button matrix with GWT

Tags: gwt, radio-button, radio-group

I would like to create a radio button matrix with GWT. Only one radio button should be selected in each row and in each column.
The think is, with GWT, a radio button cannot belong to two different RadioGroups.
Do you have any ideas how i can implement this radio button matrix?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think of two ways of doing that:

1)you can try the checkboxes and include if/else statements so as to allow only one radio button from each row to be selected.

2)possibly working with composites.

3) See this example with Ext-GWT: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/UsingRadioGrouptogroupRedioButtonsExtGWT.htm